# Using mysqli config file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am updating my existing code. I am trying to connect database using "**mysqli**". I have following files :

1. config.php
2. function.php
3. index.php
4. header.php

**config.php**

```
<?php 
$database_host = 'localhost';
$database_username = 'root';
$database_password = 'root';
$database_name = 'db_name';
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$link = mysqli_connect($database_host, $database_username, $database_password,$database_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
function mysqlQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query); 
    return $result;
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php
    include "header.php";
    include "function.php";
    $sql         =  "SELECT * FROM `posts`";
    mysqlQuery($sql);
    ?>
```

I am getting error like this ;
"Undefined variable: **link** in /var/www/folder_path/function.php on line.."
I don't know what is wrong with my code. I know this is very basic question, but still i can't find solution.
I also tried with adding line "require('config.php');" in function.php
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it really necessary to present the testcase in four separate parts?

Comment: After querying, you have to `fetch` the result and `print` them. But the error is scope related.

Answer (score 0):

You use here a function:

```
function mysqlQuery($link, $query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query); 
    return $result;
}

mysqlQuery($link, $sql);
```

In that scope the **$link** is not known give the link as parameter and it should work.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the connection since its out of scope:

**function.php**

```
function mysqlQuery($query, $link) {
                          // ^ this one also
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
    return $result;
}
```

**Index.php**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `posts`';
mysqlQuery($sql, $link);
```

Comment: Why downvote? +1, dependency injection is better than using `global`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yeah working on based on what the OP currently has, it seems okay this way